# NORM_HAMMING2 vs NORM_HAMMING

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, opencv, c++

I'm trying to use ORB features with a `cv::BFMatcher`. ORB is based on binary descriptors so HAMMING must be the choice, but I'm not sure I understand the difference between `NORM_HAMMING2` vs `NORM_HAMMING` and witch one is the right choice.

I made some test but I couldn't find any reliable  difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`BFMatcher` constructor documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#bfmatcher-bfmatcher):

> `NORM_HAMMING` should be used with ORB, BRISK and BRIEF, `NORM_HAMMING2` should be used with `ORB` when `WTA_K==3` or `4` (see `ORB::ORB` constructor description)

And [`ORB` constructor documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html#orb-orb):

> **WTA_K** - *[...]* Other possible values are 3 and 4. *[...]* Such output will occupy 2 bits, and therefore it will need a special variant of Hamming distance, denoted as `NORM_HAMMING2` (2 bits per bin).

In other words the right choice is the one that matches your `ORB` configuration (`NORM_HAMMING` when `WTA_K==2`, and `NORM_HAMMING2` when `WTA_K==3` or `WTA_K==4`), otherwise you'll wind up with incorrect norms and correspondingly poorer/inconsistent matching performance.

Comment: Nice! I thought It was just a faster algorithm. I didn't notice it was already explained in the WTA_K documentation.